# put focus in textbox when user control is load in C# winform

Tags: c#, winforms, user-controls, load

How to set focus on textbox when User control is load?

In winforms, I wrote `textbox1.focus()`, in `usercontrol.load()` but it didn't work.

Comment: Be careful with your tab order!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Try .Select() method instead.

```
textBox1.Select();
```

or

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    this.ActiveControl = textBox1;
}
```

Alternativly you could try:

```
private TextBox TextFocusedFirstLoop()
{
    // Look through all the controls on this form.
    foreach (Control con in this.Controls)
    {
    // Every control has a Focused property.
    if (con.Focused == true)
    {
        // Try to cast the control to a TextBox.
        TextBox textBox = con as TextBox;
        if (textBox != null)
        {
        return textBox; // We have a TextBox that has focus.
        }
    }
    }
    return null; // No suitable TextBox was found.
}

private void SolutionExampleLoop()
{
    TextBox textBox = TextFocusedFirstLoop();
    if (textBox != null)
    {
    // We have the focused TextBox.
    // ... We can modify or check parts of it.
    }
}
```